# Added ace editor in the modal (react-bootstrap modal) but the data is not show the value

Tags: reactjs, json, editor, ace-editor

This is my code

```
useEffect(() => {
    const loadScriptToEditor = (editorId: string, rawScript: string): void => {
      console.log('load');
      console.log(rawScript);
      // set up the ace editor environment
      const editor = ace.edit(editorId);
      const editSession = editor.getSession();
      const doc = editSession.getDocument();
      editor.renderer.setScrollMargin(10);
      // set default value
      doc.setValue('test');
      editor.renderer.updateFull();

      if (rawScript) {
        doc.setValue(rawScript);
        editor.renderer.updateFull();
      }
    };
    if (isEditorModalShow) {
      loadScriptToEditor('jsonEditor', 'test update');
    }
  }, [policy?.Content, isEditorModalShow]);
```

That is the modal body

```
<Modal
      show={isEditorModalShow}
      onHide={() => setIsEditorModalShow(false)}
      size="lg"
      centered
      dialogClassName="policy-editor-modal"
    >
      <Modal.Header className="header">
        <div>{localize('Policies.AdvancedJSON')}</div>
        <Button className="close" onClick={() => setIsEditorModalShow(false)}>
          <img src={Close} alt="Close" />
        </Button>
      </Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Body className="body">
        <AceEditor
          width="58vw"
          height="50vh"
          mode="json"
          theme="github"
          name="jsonEditor"
          showPrintMargin={false}
          readOnly={false}
          commands={[
            {
              name: 'beautify',
              bindKey: {
                win: 'Ctrl-Shift-F',
                mac: 'Cmd-Shift-F',
              },
              exec: () => {
                const editor = ace.edit('jsonEditor');
                Beautify.beautify(editor.getSession());
              },
            },
          ]}
          fontSize={12}
          setOptions={{
            showLineNumbers: true,
            useWorker: false,
          }}
          onChange={handlePolicyChange}
        />
      </Modal.Body>
```

I refered https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/3070 and they said add the updateFull() but it still not working, too
Once you click inside the editor after the change is made, the editor updates as well. I tried using editor.renderer.updateFull() and editor.renderer.updateFull(true) after the setValue call, but none of them worked.
Now it is not working althougth the modal opened
Please give a help
Thank you so much

Comment: Could you create an example on replit.com, or some other public place to make reproducing it easier?

Comment: Just found that it only fail in development mode. The production is working well. The context is I use react ace in a modal instead of element.